# conditional sorting a column dependent on another column value SQL

Tags: sql

I work for a bank and I am trying to write a query for some of our transactions and each transaction is input as the transaction amount (TXN_AMOUNT_BASE) and later identified in another column if it is a Credit or Debit (CREDIT_DEBIT_CODE).

Long term goal is to get a query that tells you the ratio of Credits to Debits for each customer.

Immediate goal is to simply separate the amounts into a Credit column or Debit column. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
    PRIMARY_CUST_SRCE_REF_ID,
    TXN_AMOUNT_BASE,
FROM 
    IDP_INTERFACE.V_L3_HPT_TRANSACTIONS
WHERE 
    CREDIT_DEBIT_CODE = 'C' AS Credit
    AND CREDIT_DEBIT_CODE = 'D' AS Debit
GROUP BY 
    (PRIMARY_CUST_SRCE_REF_ID, TXN_AMOUNT_BASE, CREDIT_DEBIT_CODE)
```

I know I am wrong on the WHERE C_D_CODE AS segment but I don't know where to start in correcting it.

Thanks

Comment: what is the error please provide input sample data and output and your select query diesnt contain same no of columns as in group by except if it was aggregate function remove credit_debit_code in group by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT PRIMARY_CUST_SRCE_REF_ID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CREDIT_DEBIT_CODE = 'C' THEN TXN_AMOUNT_BASE ELSE 0 END) AS Credit,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CREDIT_DEBIT_CODE = 'D' THEN TXN_AMOUNT_BASE ELSE 0 END) AS Debit
FROM IDP_INTERFACE.V_L3_HPT_TRANSACTIONS
WHERE CREDIT_DEBIT_CODE IN ('C', 'D')
GROUP BY PRIMARY_CUST_SRCE_REF_ID;
```

This gets you the sum of credits and debits for each customer ref.  If you want the ratio then divide the values.

Comment: Exactly @Gordon Linoff

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks! I found a solution but this is a lot cleaner.